# optimal shot angle

Tags: classical-mechanics

Our modern maths readily provides the answer to this ancient question. When shooting a projectile, what is the optimal angle that will maximise the range?

Some trigonometry and Newtonian mechanics provides the answer. 45 degrees.

I would be surprised if it wasn't figured out before trigonomrty.

Who first and how ever figured it out?